# __dyld_dyld_fatal_error upon app startup

Tags: iphone, ios, dyld

I get a `__dyld_dyld_fatal_error` when trying to run my app on an iOS3 device:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBlockOperation Referenced from: /var/mobile/Application/.......
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

My guess is that this is due to the fact that blocks aren't supported in iOS3. However, I'm having trouble tracking down which library is referencing NSBlockOperation. Is there a tool similar to dependency walker, that I can use to figure out which module it is?

Comment: did you try to set a weak references for frameworks?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you set "iOS Deployment target" in your project's settings to 3.x?

Comment: If you post the frameworks you're linking too most people could tell you if they use blocks under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your deployment target to iOS 3.x.